# sed replacement value between to matches

Tags: sed

Hi I want to replace a string coming between to symbols by using sed

example: `-amystring -bxyz`

what to replace `mystring` with `****`
value after -a can be anything like `-amystring 123 -bxyz`, `-amystring 123<newline_char>`, `-a'mystring 123' -bxyz`, `-a'mystring 123'<newline_char>`

I tried following regex but it does not work in all the cases

```
sed -re "s#(-w)([^\s\-]+)#\1**** #g"
```

can anybody help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: It'd be good if you could supply the expected output for the various cases for the sake of _clarity_.

Comment: I want to replace a string coming between -a till next "<space>-" (space followed by a hyphen)
like -a<mystring> -b ------> -a**** -b


Today I tried new regex but that is also not working in one condition if my string contains multiple space and - (not together)
sed -e 's/-a[^ ]*-*/-a\*\*\*\*/g' -e "s/\(-a\)\([^-]\+\)/\1\*\*\*\* /g"

Answer (score 0):

```
MyString="YourStringWithoutRegExSpecialCharNotEscaped"
sed "s/-a${MyString} -b/-a**** -b/g"
```

if you can escape your string for any regex key char like * + . \ / with something like

```
echo "${MyString}" | sed 's/\[*.\\/+?]/\\&/g' | read -r MyString
```

before us it in sed.

otherwise, you need to better define the edge pattern